# How to add an exception on this script

Tags: plsql

Q : 
Display all doctors that their charge per
appointment is lower than the minimum.
If exists, display a message to ask these doctors to
increase their charge per appointment by 30%.
Otherwise, provide a message in exception
handlers to notify the user of such result.
Allow the user to enter the minimum charge per
appointment.
the exception doesnt work ??

```
ACCEPT minchg PROMPT 'Enter the minimum charge per appointment: RM '

DECLARE
ex_min := chgperappt > &minchg EXCEPTION;
v_id    doctor.doc_id%TYPE;
v_name  doctor.doc_name%TYPE;
v_chg   doctor.chgperappt%TYPE;

CURSOR doc_chg IS
SELECT doc_id, doc_name, chgperappt
FROM doctor
WHERE chgperappt < &minchg;

BEGIN

OPEN doc_chg;

LOOP
FETCH doc_chg INTO v_id, v_name, v_chg;
EXIT WHEN doc_chg%NOTFOUND;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Dr. '||v_name||' ('||v_id||') is charging RM '|| v_chg);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Please increase the charge per appointment by 30% --> RM '||v_chg*1.3);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN ex_min  THEN`enter code here` 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('All charge per appointment met the minimum criteria.') ;

END LOOP;


CLOSE doc_chg;

END;
/
```

can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

The basic template for creating a user-defined exception, and handling it, is something like this:
(not your complete code example, but a snippet)

```
DECLARE

ex_min EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
    // open cursor, etc.
    IF chgperappt > &minchg THEN
       RAISE ex_min;
    END IF;

    // other code to execute if no exception is raised.

EXCEPTION
    WHEN ex_min  THEN
    // add you code here for exception handling case

END;
```

Here is a link to a [tutorial](http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-exception-handling.htm)  that goes through the process step-by-step.  Hope that helps.